# how to do a condition in map operator es6

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, angular6

I need to check a condition in map function, to prepend zeros for single digit values which means 00.00 to 09.30 remaining values be same.

currently it is prepending for all the values.

code:

```
export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  days=[];
  times =[];



ngOnInit(){
  [...this.days] = weekdays;
  // [...this.times]=IntervalTime;
  this.OnCall();
}

OnCall(){
var toInt  = time => ((h,m) => h*2 + m/30)(...time.split(':').map(parseFloat)),
    toTime = int => [Math.floor(int/2), int%2 ? '30' : '00'].join(':'),
    range  = (from, to) => Array(to-from+1).fill().map((_,i) => from + i),
    eachHalfHour = (t1, t2) => range(...[t1, t2].map(toInt)).map(toTime);
let x=[];

[...x]= eachHalfHour('0:00','15:30');

[...this.times]=x.map(i=>'0'+i);
;}

}
```

demo:[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpmvtd-xy5j1p?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

Comment: You should not do it in a separate `map`. You should do it to `Math.floor(int/2)` in `toTime`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[...this.times]=x.map(i=>{
    if ( condition ) {
        i = '0'+i;
    }

    return i;
});
```

Thanks Alexander Staroselsky, I made a typo.

Comment: With the braces `{}` you need a `return` statement to actually map the value `i = '0' + i;`. Without a return statement it will be type `void[]` and will come out as an empty array.